# Как реализованы threads в STL C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Как реализованы threads в STL C++: Являются ли они оберткой вокруг стандартных системных API: WinAPI, POSIX и др. или же организованы на более низком уровне? Спасибо.

Comment: Автор, Вы о streams или threads?

Comment: задумался я) о тредах конечно.

Answer (score 8):

В стандарте не указано, как это делать, но, как говорится, готов спорить, что в конечном итоге работа выполняется через операционную систему, но никак не на более низком уровне. Это просто не имеет никакого смысла!

Comment: Судя по упоминанию секторов диска, ответ про **streams**, однако, хотя в вопросе м.б. имелись в виду **threads**, очевидно он подходит.

Comment: @avp  *"Кстати, молодой человек! это ответ и на ваш вопрос тоже..." (с) Анекдот* - выбрасываю уточнение из ответа, и он годится и для потоков выполнения... (Сбило, наверное, то, что как раз сейчас сижу погруженный в файловые потоки...)

Comment: Классно получилось, автор-то уточнил, что спрашивал о threads. IMHO он теперь просто обязан принять ответ.

Comment: к чему вообще был задан вопрос, к тому что выбирать между std::threads или условной компиляцией между API функциями.

Comment: > условной компиляцией между API функциями. - очень тонкий момент. Лучше использовать стандартное. Но у нас в embedded (работаю с ThreadX, но касается и всяких FreeRTOS) API создания потока значительно богаче предоставленного интерфейса в `std::thread`, как минимум: мы должны иметь возможность передать указатель на стек и его размер, выставить приоритеты потока, имя (да, и такое есть, особо пригождается при отладке) и так далее. Причём, отдельные интерфейсы тех же pthread это тоже позволяют сделать, а `std::thread` - нет. В таких случаях приходится обращаться к нативным API.

Answer (score 3):

Вопросы реализации.

std::thread в libstdc++ реализованы поверх абстракции `gthread`, которая, в свою очередь, может быть обёрнута вокруг чего нужно. На Linux - вокруг `pthread`. В общем, в исходника смотреть файлы gthr.h, gthr-default.h, gthr-posix.h или gthr-signle.h.

На Windows libstdc++ не предоставляет поддержку тредов, точнее не предоставляет реализации уровня gthread для данной платформы. Поэтому проект MinGW предоставляет выбор, что будет использоваться как функционал потоков: Win32 потоки или winpthreads потоки. При использовании первого у вас не будет std::thread, потому как нет возможности сделать drop-in-place замену. Вторые, по сути, реализуют интерфейс pthread на виндовс, т.е. являются дополнительной обёрткой вокруг Win32 потоков, своеобразным адаптером.

Про то, как осуществляется поддержка потоков в других реализациях STL (например того же MSVS), я рассказать не смогу.

Comment: Забавно, первые и вторые надстройка вокруг Win32 потоков, но у первых нет возможности std::thread.

Answer (score -2):

Обёртка. Читайте исходники. Всё станет на свои места.